# How to get WebSocket Instances from embedded JettyEmbedded

Tags: java, embedded-jetty, java-websocket

I'm creating new jetty `javax.websocket` server dynamically in the following code.

```java
ServerEndpointConfig serverEndpointConfig = ServerEndpointConfig.Builder.create(
     WebSocketVpnServerChannel.class, "/" + path + "/vpn/").build();
instance.wsServerContainer.addEndpoint(serverEndpointConfig);
```

I need to get these instances to validate if no longer in use to destroy them.

Answer (score 0):

You don't.

The use of `.addEndpoint()` merely adds a configuration (not an actual endpoint) for the server to know how to create websocket endpoints **if** an incoming WebSocket upgrade request arrives to that specified path.

The container will create the Endpoints on upgrade and destroy them when the close handshake is completed (normally or abnormally)